# Error in while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to learn python,
I was trying write C/C++ code i used before in python, can anyone help me find whats wrong in this code....

```
#print 1st for 1 -> st or 2nd for 2 -> nd , etc

x = int(input('Enter a number :'))
temp = x
while temp>0:
    temp = temp % 10

if temp == 1:
    print (x, "st")
elif temp == 2:
    print (x, "nd")
elif temp == 3:
    print (x, "rd") 
else:
    print (x, "th")
```

and can you suggest few goods books to learn python, for now i was reading the documentation and its not for beginners...and i know C/C++

Comment: `print (3, "rd")` outputs `3 rd`. Use e.g. `print(x, "rd", sep='')` to avoid that space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's see how this:

```
temp = x
while temp>0:
    temp = temp % 10
```

works, using an example (`x=12345`).

```
temp = 12345
12345>0
temp = 12345%10 = 5
5>0
temp = 5%10 = 5
5>0
temp = 5%10 = 5
...
```

So it's an endless loop!

To get the last digit (which is probably what you want) just do this:

```
temp = x%10
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding good books to learn Python, I would recommend  [Head First Python](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920003434.do). It is very easy to understand and make use of your knowledge in C/C++.